# FIREBASE Hosting can't use the correct site

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have the following two hostings set up in my Firebase hosting. I don't know where the first one with the bad name came from, but anyway it's there and it's always coming up when I use firebase init from the command line as the only hosting I can use. Does anyone know how i can use Firebase init to connect my website to the second hosting address, that's the lbdsapp address? Also preferably I'd like to delete the lbds-aeb3d if possible and make the other one the default.F
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first site `lbds-aeb3d` is the main site created from your project ID, When you create the project you probably entered `lbds` which is too short for a project ID, so some random string is automatically added. So you can not delete it since it's associated with your project.

Since you have added another site, that makes your project a [multisites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites) hosting project and you will have to configure `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json` accordingly.

You can start by giving your secondary site a name to refer to when you want set it as a [deploy target](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#set_up_deploy_targets). You can do this by the following command

```
firebase target:apply hosting <target-name> <resource-name>
```

In your case, if you call it `myapp` it would be

```
firebase target:apply hosting myapp lbdsapp
```

Then firebase will generate `.firebaserc` that include `myapp` as a target

Next, you'll have to [define hosting configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#define_hosting_config) for your site in `firebase.json`

You will have to add the target name in the `hosting` config. Note that if you have more sites, you will have to configure `hosting` as array of config objects

```
{
  "hosting": {
      "target": "myapp",
      "public": ...,
      // ...

  }
}
```

When you [deploy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites#deploy_or_serve-locally) your site, you will have to specify the target

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:myapp
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to sort it out with you explanation.